# Pandas apply based on conditional from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to adjust values of one column based on a conditional in another column.

I'm using np.busday_count, but I don't want the weekend values to behave like a Monday (Sat to Tues is given 1 working day, I'd like that to be 2)

```
dispdf = df[(df.dispatched_at.isnull()==False) & (df.sold_at.isnull()==False)]

dispdf["dispatch_working_days"] = np.busday_count(dispdf.sold_at.tolist(), dispdf.dispatched_at.tolist())

for i in range(len(dispdf)):
    if dispdf.dayofweek.iloc[i] == 5 or dispdf.dayofweek.iloc[i] == 6:
        dispdf.dispatch_working_days.iloc[i] +=1
```

Sample:

```
            dayofweek   dispatch_working_days
    43159   1.0 3
    48144   3.0 3
    45251   6.0 1
    49193   3.0 0
    42470   3.0 1
    47874   6.0 1
    44500   3.0 1
    43031   6.0 3
    43193   0.0 4
    43591   6.0 3
```

Expected Results:

```
        dayofweek   dispatch_working_days
43159   1.0 3
48144   3.0 3
45251   6.0 2
49193   3.0 0
42470   3.0 1
47874   6.0 2
44500   3.0 1
43031   6.0 2
43193   0.0 4
43591   6.0 4
```

At the moment I'm using this for loop to add a working day to Saturday and Sunday values. It's slow!

Can I use a vectorization instead to speed this up. I tried using .apply but to no avail.

Comment: Could you post the results you want to see?

Comment: yep, added it in. Basically, any row of dayofweek that equals 5 or 6 needs to increase the value of dispatch_working_days by +1

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure this works, but there are more optimized implementations:

```
def adjust_dispatch(df_line):
    if df_line['dayofweek'] >= 5:
        return df_line['dispatch_working_days'] + 1
    else:
        return df_line['dispatch_working_days']         

df['dispatch_working_days'] = df.apply(adjust_dispatch, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`for` in you code could be replaced by that line:

```
dispdf.loc[dispdf.dayofweek>5,'dispatch_working_days']+=1
```

or you could use `numpy.where`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: I think this lines could give you some speedup:


`dispdf = df.dropna(subset=['dispatched_at','sold_at'])`


`dispdf["dispatch_working_days"] = np.busday_count(dispdf.sold_at.values.astype('datetime64[D]'),dispdf.dispatched_at.values.astype('datetime64[D]'))`